# How can I remove the box around the search bar in my React Material-UI app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNcCH.png)

I'm working on a React application using Material-UI, and I've encountered an issue with an unwanted box appearing around the search bar in my app. I've been trying to remove this box, but I haven't had any success so far.

Code Snippets:

I have two main components involved: Topbar.tsx and SearchAppBar.tsx.

SearchAppBar.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled, alpha } from '@mui/material/styles';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import InputBase from '@mui/material/InputBase';

const Search = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  position: 'relative',
  borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
  backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
  },
  marginLeft:'auto',
  width: '100%',
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
  },
}));

const SearchIconWrapper = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
  height: '100%',
  position: 'absolute',
  pointerEvents: 'none',
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
}));

const StyledInputBase = styled(InputBase)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: 'inherit',
  '& .MuiInputBase-input': {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
    paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)})`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
    width: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: '12ch',
      '&:focus': {
        width: '20ch',
      },
    },
  },
}));

export default function SearchAppBar() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <Search>
            <SearchIconWrapper>
              <SearchIcon />
            </SearchIconWrapper>
            <StyledInputBase
              placeholder="Search…"
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
            />
          </Search>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Topbar.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import AdbIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Adb';
import SearchAppBar from './SearchAppBar';

const pages = ['Men', 'Women', 'Kids'];
const settings = ['Profile', 'Account', 'Dashboard', 'Logout'];

function Topbar() {
  const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
  const [anchorElUser, setAnchorElUser] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);

  const handleOpenNavMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleOpenUserMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorElUser(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleCloseNavMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElNav(null);
  };

  const handleCloseUserMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Toolbar disableGutters>
          <AdbIcon sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' }, mr: 1 }} />
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            noWrap
            component="a"
            href="#app-bar-with-responsive-menu"
            sx={{
              mr: 2,
              display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' },
              fontFamily: 'monospace',
              fontWeight: 700,
              letterSpacing: '.3rem',
              color: 'inherit',
              textDecoration: 'none',
            }}
          >
            LOGO
          </Typography>

          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' } }}>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls="menu-appbar"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Menu
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElNav}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'bottom',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
              onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
              sx={{
                display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' },
              }}
            >
              {pages.map((page) => (
                <MenuItem key={page} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                  <Typography textAlign="center">{page}</Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </Box>
          <AdbIcon sx={{ display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' }, mr: 1 }} />
          <Typography
            variant="h5"
            noWrap
            component="a"
            href="#app-bar-with-responsive-menu"
            sx={{
              mr: 2,
              display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' },
              flexGrow: 1,
              fontFamily: 'monospace',
              fontWeight: 700,
              letterSpacing: '.3rem',
              color: 'inherit',
              textDecoration: 'none',
            }}
          >
            LOGO
          </Typography>
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}>
            {pages.map((page) => (
              <Button
                key={page}
                onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
                sx={{ my: 2, color: 'white', display: 'block' }}
              >
                {page}
              </Button>
            ))}
          </Box>

          <SearchAppBar/>

          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
            <Tooltip title="Open settings">
              <IconButton onClick={handleOpenUserMenu} sx={{ p: 0 }}>
                <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg" />
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
            <Menu
              sx={{ mt: '45px' }}
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElUser}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElUser)}
              onClose={handleCloseUserMenu}
            >
              {settings.map((setting) => (
                <MenuItem key={setting} onClick={handleCloseUserMenu}>
                  <Typography textAlign="center">{setting}</Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </Container>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
export default Topbar;
```

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

I've tried the following steps to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

Checked for conflicting CSS styles that might affect the search bar.
Verified that Material-UI styles are not unintentionally applied to create the box.
Examined parent components (such as Topbar.tsx) to ensure no additional styles are causing the issue.
Checked the browser's developer console for CSS warnings or errors.
Inspected the element using browser DevTools to view computed styles.
Request for Assistance:

I'm seeking guidance on how to remove or correctly style the search bar in my Material-UI app to get rid of the unwanted box. Any help or insights into what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

If you need additional code or context to assist with debugging, please let me know, and I'll provide more details.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: It's because you have an MUI `AppBar` component (`SearchAppBar.tsx`) nested inside of another MUI `AppBar` component (`Topbar.tsx`). Remove the `<AppBar>` component completely from `SearchAppBar.tsx`.